# I have a Type Error with >= and a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input, int

```
gclass = int(input(""))

if gclass == 1:
    gclass = "Knight"
    knight()
if gclass == 2:
    gclass = "Sorcerer"
    sorcerer()
if gclass == 3:
    gclass = "Archer"
    archer()
if gclass == 4:
    gclass = "THE CHOSEN ONE"
    chosenone()
if gclass >= 5:
    print("Don't do that. ENDING GAME")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()
if gclass == "":
    print("Don't do that. ENDING GAME")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()
print("You chose:",gclass,)
```

This is the code that isnt working and the error

```
File "main.py", line 115, in <module>
    if gclass >= 5:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I don't understand because before the code did not have int but now it does and neither of them work properly or how I want them too. I am a beginner and am making a simple game so anything complicated might be too complicated for me but I can understand pretty basic stuff.

Comment: What does the error message say? Trust it and work backwards. (Because it's really not misleading..)

Comment: You are assigning a string value to `gclass` in the previous `if` statements. In this scenario you should have used `elif`s instead of `if`. Even in that case `if gclass == "":` would've failed because `gclass` is an `int`.

Comment: FWIW: using *different variables* will help avoid cross-type confusion

Comment: Use `elif` when you have mutually exclusive `if` tests. And use `else:` for the final test that should handle all other cases.

Comment: Thank you Selcuk it worked you can try it here: https://Diatron.imcuckoo.repl.run

Comment: use `print(type(gclass))` before the line where the error happens to debug it's actual type at the time of execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `if` statements when you should be using `elif` and `else` statements. Your code will work when you do it like this.

```py
gclass = int(input(""))

if gclass == 1:
    gclass = "Knight"
    knight()
elif gclass == 2:
    gclass = "Sorcerer"
    sorcerer()
elif gclass == 3:
    gclass = "Archer"
    archer()
elif gclass == 4:
    gclass = "THE CHOSEN ONE"
    chosenone()
else:
    print("Don't do that. ENDING GAME")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()
print("You chose: " + gclass)
```

Also for the future `""` isn't possible for an int value and you should probably have a try catch for inputting ints.

Answer (score 0):

As one of your if statements is changing the `gclass` variable to a string, the error will occur.

You could use a new variable like `gclass_text` as following:

```
import time

gclass = int(input(""))

if gclass == 1:
    gclass_text = "Knight"
    knight()
if gclass == 2:
    gclass_text = "Sorcerer"
    sorcerer()
if gclass == 3:
    gclass_text = "Archer"
    archer()
if gclass == 4:
    gclass_text = "THE CHOSEN ONE"
    chosenone()
if gclass >= 5:
    print("Don't do that. ENDING GAME")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()
if gclass == "":
    print("Don't do that. ENDING GAME")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()

print("You chose:", gclass_text)
```